# Query Transact Sql - SubSelect

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una consulta sql que no puedo determinar,

```
 (
    SELECT  (
        SELECT e.nombre
            FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS e 
            WHERE e.idEtapa = etd.idEtapa
        )AS etapa
        FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
        INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd ON etd.[idEtapaTipoDocumento] = red.[idEtapaTipoDocumento]
        INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS e ON e.[idEtapa] = etd.[idEtapa]
        INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Documento] AS rd ON rd.[idRegistroDocumento] = red.[idRegistroDocumento]
        INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS fa ON fa.[idFactura] = rd.[idDocumento]
        INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura_Orden_Compra] AS fo ON fo.[idFactura] = fa.[idFactura]
        INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Tipo_Documento] AS td ON td.[idTipoDocumento] = rd.[idTipoDocumento]
        WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(13), fo.[orden_compra]) = oc.[numero_documento]
            AND td.[nombre] = 'Factura'
            AND red.recepcionado = 1
            AND red.idEtapaTipoDocumento=(select max(red.idEtapaTipoDocumento) 
                                              FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
                                              where red.recepcionado='1' )
)AS estado
```

mi problema esta en el 3er `AND` de la 2da subselect `AND red.idEtapaTipoDocumento=` aca es donde no logro trar el estado de la  etapa.
aca debiera traerme el estado mas actualizado de la tb_registro_etapa_documento segun la query anterior.
pero simplemente me trae el dato en NULL.
si a este `AND` le asiganara un valor de la etapa, por ejemplo:

```
AND red.idEtapaTipoDocumento='9'
```

me trae el estado para todos aquellos que si cumplen(pero no es la idea).
ya que necesito que me traiga el estado de la etapa para todos los datos.

algo me falla en esta 3da subselect, si alguien me pudiera ayudar lo agradeceria.

espero me puedan entender y ayudar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Este query anda? select max(red.idEtapaTipoDocumento) 
                                              FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
                                              where red.recepcionado='1'

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por tu consejo.

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por tu consejo.
la query que me indicas si anda, pero me trae la etapa mas alta de la tabla, cabe destacar qjue en este misma tabla se puede repetir la etapa, pero el recepcionado es quien la hace activa o no. en este caso recepcionado en valor 1 es el que tomo.
ahora cabe tambien mencionar que esta query que me indicas si funciona, pero debo ligarla con el dato correspondiente que me trae la query principal.

Comment: Francisco, antes que nada, te comento que el que te estuvo consultando es gbianchi (al final del comentario aparece el autor) yo simplemente edite tu pregunta para que se viera mejor el código. En cuanto a tu pregunta: desconociendo las relaciones entre las tablas es muy difícil poder ayudarte, además de por sí la consulta es compleja.

Comment: Lo único que puedo comentarte es: `select max(red.idEtapaTipoDocumento) FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red where red.recepcionado='1'` te va a devolver un único registro, aquel máximo que en toda la tabla tenga  `recepcionado='1'`, por consiguiente te invalida toda la consulta.

Comment: si amigo, gracias por el consejo, logre encontrar la solución a este tema. como soy nuevo, nose como darlo por cerrado.

Comment: Prueba, plantear la pregunta de forma más sencilla, explicando primero que es lo que buscas, como para los que no conocemos nada podamos entender, si muestras código, reducelo a las tablas mínimas que sirvan para explicar el problema, agrega las estructuras de las mismas (no es necesario todos los campos pero si los que intervienen en el query) y como son las relaciones entre cada tabla. Por último, un ejemplo de la salida y otro de lo realmente esperado puede ayudar mucho. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre traer el estado con la siguiente query:

`(
SELECT e.nombre 
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd 
ON etd.[idEtapaTipoDocumento] = red.[idEtapaTipoDocumento]
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS e 
ON e.[idEtapa] = etd.[idEtapa]
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Documento] AS rd 
ON rd.[idRegistroDocumento] = red.[idRegistroDocumento]
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS fa 
ON fa.[idFactura] = rd.[idDocumento]
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura_Orden_Compra] AS fo 
ON fo.[idFactura] = fa.[idFactura]
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Tipo_Documento] AS td 
ON td.[idTipoDocumento] = rd.[idTipoDocumento]
WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(13), fo.[orden_compra]) = oc.[numero_documento]
AND red.idEtapaTipoDocumento = (SELECT MAX(red.idEtapaTipoDocumento) 
                FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
                INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd 
                ON etd.[idEtapaTipoDocumento] = red.[idEtapaTipoDocumento]
                INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS e 
                ON e.[idEtapa] = etd.[idEtapa]
                INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Documento] AS rd 
                ON rd.[idRegistroDocumento] = red.[idRegistroDocumento]
                INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS fa 
                ON fa.[idFactura] = rd.[idDocumento]
                INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura_Orden_Compra] AS fo 
                ON fo.[idFactura] = fa.[idFactura]
                INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Tipo_Documento] AS td 
                ON td.[idTipoDocumento] = rd.[idTipoDocumento]
                WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(13), fo.[orden_compra]) = oc.[numero_documento]
                and red.recepcionado='1'
                )
) as estado`

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, en primer término no necesitas esas subconsultas, solamente JOIN's

la segunda subconsulta recupera el nombre de la etapa, que ya tienes en la tercera subconsulta, podrías eliminar las 2 primeras así:

```
    SELECT e.nombre
    FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd 
      ON etd.[idEtapaTipoDocumento] = red.[idEtapaTipoDocumento]
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS e 
      ON e.[idEtapa] = etd.[idEtapa]
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Documento] AS rd 
      ON rd.[idRegistroDocumento] = red.[idRegistroDocumento]
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS fa 
      ON fa.[idFactura] = rd.[idDocumento]
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura_Orden_Compra] AS fo 
      ON fo.[idFactura] = fa.[idFactura]
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Tipo_Documento] AS td 
      ON td.[idTipoDocumento] = rd.[idTipoDocumento]
    WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(13), fo.[orden_compra]) = oc.[numero_documento]
      AND td.[nombre] = 'Factura'
      AND red.recepcionado = 1
      AND red.idEtapaTipoDocumento=
      (
        select max(red.idEtapaTipoDocumento) 
        FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
        where red.recepcionado='1' 
      )
    ) AS estado
```

Con eso eliminas las subconsultas anidadas.

Ahora para recuperar el máximo id de la etapa que al parecer es numérico, deberías crear una función a la cual le envías el identificador del objeto al cual pertenece el registro de la etapa y devuelves el máximo. En donde esta el  lo reemplazas con el nombre del campo que identifica de forma única el objeto para el cual quieres el máximo estado.

```
    SELECT e.nombre, dbo.registroEtapaEstadoMaximo(<identificador>) as maximoRegistroEstado  
    FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd 
      ON etd.[idEtapaTipoDocumento] = red.[idEtapaTipoDocumento]
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS e 
      ON e.[idEtapa] = etd.[idEtapa]
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Documento] AS rd 
      ON rd.[idRegistroDocumento] = red.[idRegistroDocumento]
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS fa 
      ON fa.[idFactura] = rd.[idDocumento]
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura_Orden_Compra] AS fo 
      ON fo.[idFactura] = fa.[idFactura]
    INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Tipo_Documento] AS td 
      ON td.[idTipoDocumento] = rd.[idTipoDocumento]
    WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(13), fo.[orden_compra]) = oc.[numero_documento]
      AND td.[nombre] = 'Factura'
      AND red.recepcionado = 1
```

Busca en google cómo implementar funciones en SQL Server TSQL

Adicionalmente te doy un consejo para que mejores como programador de Bases de Datos.

Siempre ten claro el modelo de datos (El concepto de relaciones entre tablas), en donde esta la información que necesitas?, crear las consultas con los join que requieras. Los criterios o filtros que requieres y finalmente si es necesario agrupar datos.

Según tu pregunta, afirmas que necesitas traer la etapa para todos los datos, pero solo estas trayendo la información de la etapa y el máximo estado, en donde están los "datos".

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: hola jorge, muchas gracias por tu consejo, cabe señalar que esta query es mucho mas extensa, solo pegue la subconsulta donde tengo el problema.
segun lo que me indicas, revisare como podría traer el dato que necesito con una función. como me indicas creo que por ahí esta mi problema.